# jcombobox (showing name and returning code)

Tags: java, swing

I have a table in my database where i m having some names and corresponding code now what i want   is   to show the names in the jcombobox but when i select any name from that jcombobox a corresponding code should be returned.

table is like

name       code 
a           1    
b           2
c 3

Comment: Where is that table? Is it in a `JTable`? or in a `Map`? Or in a file? And where do you want it to be returned?

Comment: Table is in my database. I am using a query to get all the names from the table and then display them in jcombobox. All i want is that when i use getSelectedItem() then it will give me the code corresponding to that name from the table(in database).

Answer (score 1):

You will need to store the codes e.g. in an `ArrayList` and retrieve the current code using the combo box's selection index.

```
private JComboBox comboBox;
private List<Integer> codes;

private void createUI() {
    comboBox = new JComboBox();
    codes = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    addItem("one", 42);
    addItem("two", 127);
    comboBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println(comboBox.getSelectedIndex());
            System.out.println(codes.get(comboBox.getSelectedIndex()));
        }
    });
    add(comboBox);
}

private void addItem(String name, int code) {
    comboBox.addItem(name);
    codes.add(code);
}
```

Comment: I don't really like that solution because you split up the data in separate datastructures (List, JComboBox).

Comment: Agreed, but it is faster to implement. Extracting a helper class and a custom renderer could be done later - which means 'never' :-) Anyway, I upvoted your more elegant solution.

Comment: Agreed, your solution does not need a wrapper class which makes it faster to implement. So it's a valid "fast'n'dirty" solution. +1

Comment: -1 _faster to implement_ is the worst driving force ever for anything except the most trivial applications ;-)

Comment: @kleopatra which might be the case here

Answer (score 1):

Why not wrap the code & name in object & using a list cell renderer, only render the ame, but then you can get the returned object from .getSelectedItem & extract the code from it

Comment: You don't need to have a non-default cell renderer, just overwrite `Object#toString()` in your wrapper class to display the name... (see my answer)

Comment: +1 a custom renderer is spot on - that's Swing small coin for custom visual representation. Everything else is more or less suboptimal

Answer (score 0):

have look at

1. [ItemListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/itemlistener.html) (fired events always twice)
2. [ActionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html)

Comment: i can use ItemListener and get the selected name from the JComboBox but how do i get the code for that name??

Comment: suppose i have table like this

a   1<br/>
b   2<br/>
c   3<br/>

now i m showing a,b,c in the jcombobox and when using getSelectedItem i want to get the code(eg 1 or 2 or 3) for that item(e.g a or b or c)
hope you understand my question..

Comment: i can't show the view of table there bt consider the <br/> as new line.
look for the edit in the question

Answer (score 0):

You can create a wrapper class - let's call it `TableElement`:

```
class TableElement {
  public String name;
  public double value;

  public TableElement(String n, double v) {
    name = n;
    value = v;
  }

  // this is what is shown in the JComboBox
  public String toString() {
    return name;
  }
}
```

Then you can create an array of all your table elements and create your `JComboBox` like this

```
Vector<TableElement> vect = new Vector<TableElement>();
for (/* all your table elements */) 
  vect.add(new TableElement(elementName, elementValue);
JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox(vect);
```

and read it out like this:

```
TableElement selected = (TableElement)comboBox.getSelectedItem();
System.out.println("name = " +selected.name + ",value = " + selected.value);
```

Comment: -1 while possible, it's not recommended: never-ever tweak the data for view reasons. Instead, implement a renderer - that's the part which is responsible for custom views.

Comment: @kleopatra Where did I tweak it? You **will** have to put it in some sort or array/List in order to show it in the JComboBox. You mean the `toString`? Or the general approach with a wrapper class? If so, could you provide a valid solution instead of just downvoting every answer without giving an alternative?

Comment: btw the sole purpose of `toString` is for viewing purposes. That method should never be used for something else...

Comment: @kleopatra in the case that two (or more) Items have got the same String value, then there aren't another way, JComboBox & JList can't do that, displaying is correct, but all methods for getXxx(Xxx) are wrong :-)

Comment: you might want to view the same thingy (your TableElement) in different .. well .. views, showing different aspects. Then, what do you do? Implement a new wrapper per view? You certainly can, but that's not Swing'ish, as there is a class _designed_ to take over custom visual representations BTW: I already gave the alternative ... Read the part of my first comment which starts with _instead_ :-) And I didn't downvote _every_ answer only the incorrect/suboptimal ones, the correct got an upvote.

Comment: @kleopatra in the case that you put {"Color", "Color", "Color", "Color"} to the JComboBox then JComboBox#getXxx(Xxx) returns nonsence, because in this thread is everything possible...